# Importing PDFSharp Library to Unity

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, pdfsharp

**Please see bottom for latest update.**

I've looked elsewhere on the web and there doesn't seem to be a great deal of information regarding the use of PDFSharp in Unity.

PDFSharp looked like a good, simple solution to get my app to create pdf files, so I downloaded the library into my project's assets folder to get started.

This seemed to work at first, as the desired syntax was now available in my scripts in MonoDevelop. When I tried the run the app, however, it failed to compile and displayed the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Being relatively new to Unity and completely new to any form of library extensions/file creation, I'm not sure what to do to resolve this. There's an awful lot of files in the PDFSharp folder to go through manually trying to find the root of the problem.

Does anyone have experience using PDFSharp with Unity, has encountered a similar problem and could help me solve it? I would be very grateful for any help.

*Using the latest version of Unity with MonoDevelop and PDFSharp 1.31.*

Using PDFSharp 1.32 threw up rather a few more errors: http://pastebin.com/PLUdZRbp

One link I looked at, but couldn't make much sense of: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1206

**Update:** It turns out that I'd downloaded the source code instead of the assembly, so I downloaded that instead. The result was a lot better, but now it's throwing a TypeLoadException:

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'PdfSharp.Charting.Renderers.RendererParameters' from assembly 'PdfSharp.Charting-WPF, Version=1.32.2608.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb'.
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

It also appears that where I've used the line PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(); in my script, it's throwing this error:

Assets/Scripts/Exporter.cs(18,17): error CS0433: The imported type `PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument' is defined multiple times

**Note:** The TypeLoadException error, when the project is played with any scripts which use that library removed, actually causes Unity to crash to desktop.

Comment: What does "latest version of PDFSharp" mean? PDFsharp DLLs 1.32 or PDFsharp DLLs 1.50? Maybe you get more useful error messages if you download the PDFsharp 1.32 source code and reference the PDFsharp projects from your solution.

Comment: @ThomasH Sorry, I've just realised the version I'm using is 1.31, not 1.32. or 1.50. It seems the link I followed was a little outdated. I probably should have looked around to see if that was the most recent version or not. I'll try 1.32 instead and see if that works. I'll update here either way. Oddly, I can't seem to find 1.50 for download anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasH Sorry for commenting again, but I've tried out 1.32. It came up with more errors, than before and I've attached those in a Pastebin to the original question. I couldn't find any mention of a version of PDFSharp above version 1.32, though. I'm not quite sure what you mean by referencing the projects from my solution?

Comment: I am not familiar with Unitiy. With Visual Studio you can add existing C# projects to your solution (instead if copying DLLs to your assets). This will allow you to step through the PDFsharp code once it compiles or correct compilation errors in PDFsharp. 1.50 beta is available on NuGet (DLLs only - try the CORE build if you want to give it a try). The source code for PDFsharp 1.32 is IMHO the better approach (says one without any Mono experience).

Comment: Re pastebin error messages: you didn't use the project files that come with PDFsharp. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31295012/1015447

Comment: @ThomasH Unfortunately MonoDevelop doesn't seem to have that option, and trying something similar through Unity was unsuccessful (apart from placing it in the assets folder, which is supposed to import it into Mono automatically - that part of it appears to be working). I think I've managed to get it close to working, but it's a bit hit-and-miss. I updated above, as before.

Comment: @Kratos were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro sadly not. I ended up using XmlWriter and xDocument to write the file to .txt. Simpler, but not as neat. I would have preferred to get this working but it was taking such a long time to try and find the source of the problem that I took the easier route.